# split a string and store

Tags: sql

I have a string like this

```
message_type=something, Hours=0, SQM=0, user_name=xxxxx, Boards=0, Charge=0, Proofs=0
```

and i need to get all the values after equal to(=) (something,xxxxx,0,0,0,0) we have to store them in variables using SQL

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: "Store them in variables using SQL"? Where is the string now and where do you want to store it and why do you think you need SQL for it?

Comment: that string is a column in dbms and i have to get it and split that string and store the values variables. i am writing a stored procedure  so i need SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need something like this?

```
SELECT
    RIGHT('message_type=something', (CHARINDEX('=', REVERSE('message_type=something'), 0)) - 1)
```

Comment: Both RIGHT, CHARINDEX and REVERSE are product specific functions, in an answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least inform OP which dbms your answer is for!

Comment: It is for Microsoft SQL Server.. That is why i said "If I understood correctly"

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code . Its working fine with SQL Server 2012:

```
    BEGIN
          DECLARE @str VARCHAR(2000)
          DECLARE @input VARCHAR(4000)
          DECLARE @ind Int
          DECLARE @Count int 
          DECLARE @max int 
          SET @max =0

          DECLARE @Result TABLE (ID int identity(1,1),value varchar(1000))
          SET @input ='message_type=something, Hours=0, SQM=0, user_name=xxxxx, Boards=0, Charge=0, Proofs=0'
          IF(@input is not null)
              BEGIN
                    SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
                    WHILE @ind > 0
                        BEGIN
                              SET @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
                              SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
                              INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
                              SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
                        END
              SET @str = @input
              INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
             END

          SET @Count = (SELECT Max(ID) from @Result)

             WHILE @Count > @max
              BEGIN
               SET @max = @max +1
               DECLARE @Value varchar(1000)
               SET @Value = (SELECT SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX('=', value) + 1, LEN(value)) from @Result WHERE ID =@max)
               SELECT @value
             END
    END
```

In the last while loop you can assign to the corresponding variable as required.

Comment: dbms is sybase and when i tried the code i got a error like this Function -CHARINDEX invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
`select wm_concat(substr(val,instr(val,'=')+1)) from (select  regexp_substr ('message_type=something, 
Hours=0, SQM=0, user_name=xxxxx, Boards=0, Charge=0, Proofs=0', '[^,]+', 1, rn) as val
 from dual
 cross
 join (select rownum as rn
         from dual
      connect by level <= 7));`
```